# How test the accuracy for tensorflow lite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, evaluate

I train a CNN tensorflow model, and convert for a tensorflow lite model. And now i want to know  how can i make the evaluate for the TFLITE model.

I make this code :

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_save)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details() 


interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], ((len(X_test)), 180,180, 3))
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(output_details[0]['index'], (len(X_test), 4))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], X_test)
interpreter.invoke()

loss, accuracy = interpreter.evaluate(X_test)
```

But, show me the error:

```
'Interpreter' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

After this I tried:

```
loss, accuracy = interpreter.evaluate_tflite(X_test)
```

But apparently this just it works for Model Makers model.
So now i just don't know how to preceed.

Answer (score 0):

If your tflite model has a signature, then you can leverage the signature, see the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/signatures#python).

If the model doesn't have signatures, then you can see what are the outputs like this

```
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
# Assuming you have 2 outputs
output_1 = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
output_2 = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
```

The signature is the suggested way, and is safer for output reordering issues.